# I am not able to see the menu bar of VLC media player

Tags: 14.04, vlc

Since last few days I am not able to close the VLC media player, through 'cross' button and I have to use 'Alt+F4' to close it. I cannot see the menu bar. 
I have uninstalled and reinstalled the VLC media player and the problem still exists.
What should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this command in terminal:

> vlc -Iqt4 --reset-config --reset-plugins-cach

Try to do clean re-installation of vlc:

> sudo apt-get purge vlc
>
> rm -r ~/.config/vlc
>
> rm -r ~/.cache/vlc

then again install:

> sudo apt-get install vlc